# Why do some materials follow Lambert's cosine law?

Tags: radiometry

I perfectly understand Lambert's cosine law, so I can apply it, it isn't really that hard (now that I got it :)
$$I_n=I_\theta*\cos\theta$$
What I don't understand is why some materials follow this law. What is it with(in) these materials that makes them follow this law? Also, why is the factor exactly $\cos\theta$ and not something else like $5\cos\theta$ or $\pi\cos\theta$ or any other function of $\theta$ that has values between 0 and 1?

I also understand that if you want to have a surface that has an apparent brightness independent of the viewing angle, then you'll have to use a material for which $I_n=I_\theta*\cos\theta$ so that the viewing angle nicely cancels out in the radiance definition. My surprise is that it wouldn't be so hard to find this material, most surfaces are kind of lambertian (at least if you see them from far enough).

My intuition tells me that it has something to do with probability and calculus and applying Snell's law an infinite number of times and somehow a cosine will pop-up. Am I right? Yes or no, what are the maths and physics of materials in general (except those which are obviously not lambertian, like mirrors) that lead to Lambert's cosine law?

Comment: I think this question is wholly answered by [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law) for the cosine law.

Comment: It is not explained at all in the wikipedia article. All that wikipedia article explains (not entirely correct or at least not using standard conventions, but that's a whole different discussion) is how you should apply Lambert's cosine Law, but it doesn't explain anything about why this law (approximately) exists in some real-world materials.

Comment: Oh, you want to know *why* some materials are well approximated as *ideal* diffuse reflectors?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, basically, yes, but I used more words and wrote the Lambert's cosine law itself so that people who might answer won't have the option to interpret what diffuse or ideal actually means.